# c: strtod: double pointer vs. reference to single pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Works great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
  char number[]= "a123.45", *strtod_eptr;
  double num;

  num=strtod(number, &strtod_eptr);
  if (strtod_eptr == number){
    printf("Error: no number found.\n");
  }
  else{ printf("%f\n", num+7);
  }

  return 0;
 }
```

Does not work. Second argument in strtod() changed type.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void){
    char number[]= "a123.45", **strtod_epptr;
    double num;

    num=strtod(number, strtod_epptr);
    if (*strtod_epptr == number){
        printf("Error: no number found.\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("%f\n", num+7);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Compiler warns about uninitialized strtod_epptr but no compile errors.

```
strol_test.c:7:5: warning: ‘strtod_epptr’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```

Program crashes (seg fault) at the if() statement.

Compiler command (in both cases):

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic -o "strol_test" "strol_test.c"
```

Why does this happen? Why does gcc complains about uninitialized **strtod_epptr while being totaly fine with (similarily uninitialized ?) *strtod_eptr ?
And what goes wrong when dereferencing **strtod_epptr? AFAIK:

```
char *ptr;
...strtod(...,&ptr)
```

should be the same as

```
char **ptr;
...strtod(...,ptr)
```

but obviously it is not. What am I missing?

Comment: Pointer needs to point some valid memory address. Where does the pointer is pointing to?

Comment: The second argument you pass to `strtod()` has the same *type* in both cases (`char **`), but a different *value*.

Comment: Additionally, C does not have references.

Comment: Here is one MSVC [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxsfc1ab.aspx) of `strtod` with an example. Please read this or another man page.

Comment: It is OK to use the address of an uninitialized variable. It is not OK to use the value of such a variable.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: What do you mean by 'C does not have references'? AFAIK &sth is one, or isn't it? (Sorry if that's a dumb question. I've got a electronics background and no theory in CS, just a DIY C learner so bear with me, please.) A brief explanation or a meaningfull(for ordinary folks) link would be great.

Comment: @K.Nick, no, `&sth` is a *pointer*.  Pointers and references are similar things, but not the same (observe that C++ has *both*), and the difference occasionally matters.

Answer (score 4):

Think about memory.

When you write `char *str` you asked the compiler to allocate memory for a char pointer. Now when you send the address of `str` to a function, as `&str` that value inside str can be changed.

Now the other way around.

When you write `char **str` you asked the compiler to allocate memory for a pointer to a char pointer. That means there is NO memory allocation for the char pointer. If you dereference that pointer now, it will point to nothing meaningful.

Now, you passed `str` to `strtod()`. The function now does `*str = something()`. BUT that place does not exist in the memory. That bucket was not created and allocated.

In the future, always pass the ADDRESS of an already existing variable. If not, there is no variable the function can update...

Answer (score 3):

`strtod` expects a double-pointer (pointer to pointer), because it wants to tell
the user the location where it stopped reading. So it has to change where a
pointer is pointing, thus it cannot take a (single) pointer, it has to take a
pointer to a pointer.

> *man strtod*
>
> ```
> #include <stdlib.h>
> double strtod(const char *nptr, char **endptr);
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> These functions return the converted value, if any.
>
> If `endptr` is not `NULL`, **a pointer to the character after the last character used in the conversion is stored in the location referenced
>   by `endptr`.**

That means that the pointer you pass through `endptr` must point to a valid
`char`-pointer, that's why

```
char number[]= "a123.45", *strtod_eptr;
num=strtod(number, &strtod_eptr);
```

works well because `&strtod_eptr` returns the address of the `strtod_eptr`
variable, it returns a pointer to a pointer. `strtod` can then use the pointer
to a pointer to change where the original pointer (`strtod_eptr`) will
point.

Internally `strtod` will do something like this:

```
double strtod(const char *nptr, char **endptr)
{
    size_t i;
    double converted_value;
    ...
    if(endptr != NULL)
    {
        // i is the index the character after the last
        // character used in the conversion
        *endptr = &(nptr[i]);
    }

    return converted_value;
}
```

When `endptr` points to a valid location, dereferencing it won't be a problem.

However

```
char number[]= "a123.45", **strtod_eptr;
num=strtod(number, strtod_eptr);
```

doesn't work, because `strtod_eptr` is an **uninitialzed** pointer that points
to nowhere in particular. When `strtod` does `*endptr = &(nptr[i])`, it is
trying to write a value in an undefined memory location, this is undefined behaviour and the
segfault is a manifestation of that.

This would work however:

```
char number[]= "a123.45", *end, **strtod_eptr;

strtod_eptr = &end;
num=strtod(number, strtod_eptr);
```

Because in this case `strtod_eptr` would point to a valid location.